# Duda teórica sobre condiciones de carrera en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Esto es un *recorte* de un archivo que utilizo actualmente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link id="SKIN.CSS" rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8"/>
<script id="APP.JS" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script id="GUI.JS" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

window.Gui = { };

window.App = { }

( function( ) {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest( ),
      remains = 3, // Archivos que faltan por cargar.
      response,
      tmp;

  // Solicitamos los archivos a cargar.
  ajax.onreadystatechange = onResponse;
  ajax.open( 'POST', 'config.php' );
  ajax.send( );

  function onResponse( ) {
    if( ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) && ( ajax.status == 200 ) ) {
      response = JSON.parse( ajax.responseText );

      // Cargamos el resto de archivos.
      tmp = document.getElementById( 'SKIN.CSS' );
      tmp.onload = onLoaded;
      tmp.href = response.skin;

      tmp = document.getElementById( 'APP.JS' );
      tmp.onload = onLoaded;
      tmp.src = response.app;

      tmp = document.getElementById( 'GUI.JS' );
      tmp.onload = onLoaded;
      tmp.src = response.gui;
    }
  }

  function onLoaded( ) {
    -- remains;
console.log( 'remains:', remains );

    if( !remains )
      setTimeout( Run, 0 );
  }

  function Run( ) {
  console.log( 'Se llamó a RUN( ).' );

    Gui.Init( );
    setTimeout( App.Run, 0 );
  }
} )( );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Realizo una llamada AJAX para obtener los nombres de 3 archivos a cargar, y establezco *a mano* los atributos `src=` y `href=` según corresponda, para cargarlos dinamicamente.

El asunto está en

```
function onLoaded( ) {
  -- remains;
  console.log( 'remains:', remains );

  if( !remains )
    setTimeout( Run, 0 );
}
```

Este código, en *otros* lenguajes, sería motivo mas que suficiente de *expulsión directa del gremio*.

Supongamos que ocurre la siguiente secuencia de eventos:

1. Se carga el `SKIN.CSS`.
2. Se llama a la función `loaded( )`, que se ejecuta por completo. `remains === 2'.
3. Se carga el `APP.JS`.
4. Se llama a la funcion `loaded( )`.
5. Dentro de `loaded( )`, *decremento* `remains`, que pasa a `=== 1`.
6. Antes de entrar en el `if`, **se carga el `GUI.JS`**.
7. Se ejecuta `loaded( )`. `remains === 0`.
8. Entro en el `if( )`. La condición se cumple. Se ejecuta `App.Run( )`.
9. El navegador continua en el punto `6`, pero ahora **ya puedo entrar en el `if( )`, porque `remains === 0`** (**no** lo era cuando se interrumpió).
10. Se llama **por segunda vez** a `App.Run( )`.

¿ Esta secuencia de eventos **es posible** en Javascript, o el lenguaje garantiza que ninguna función será interrumpida por ningún evento ?

Comment: Javascript es monohilo, por lo que los eventos se atienden en secuencia, sin interrupción del anterior. Básicamente usa un planificador [run-to-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_to_completion_scheduling) (ejecuta hasta la finalización). En servidores Node.js se aumenta el paralelismo y se aprovechan los núcleos del servidor aumentando el número de servidores, balanceando las peticiones entre ellos, pero dentro de cada servidor un script mal diseñado podría ralentizar el resto de peticiones que corren en el mismo, pero no afecta al de otros servidores.

Comment: Bueno, se me olvidaban los [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Usando_web_workers), hay algo más de información en https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2015/02/26/the-path-to-parallel-javascript/ sobre caminos para alcanzar el paralelismo en javascript. Según veo a partir de febrero de 2017 se ha agregado a la especificación ECMAScript: https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript_sharedmem

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias por el comentario, pero no quiero usar varios hilos ni nada parecido. Solo me preguntaba hasta que punto los eventos *asíncronos* pueden interrumpir un código actualmente en ejecución. ¿ El código que muestro funcionará universalmente en cualquier navegador, o hay posibilidad de que alguno, en su implementación del lenguaje y los eventos, llame a `App.Run( )` **2 veces** ? Por supuesto, sin tener en cuenta posibles *bugs* de los navegadores; ciñéndonos exclusivamente a la especificación del lenguaje.

Comment: Ciñéndonos a la definición del lenguaje, es monohilo. No hay más, ni siquiera ECMAScript soporta multihilo, la librería de memoria compartida es para compartir datos entre diferentes procesos que corren en la misma máquina, pero un único proceso sólo puede contener un hilo y ejecutar los eventos en orden sin paradas del código por cambio de hilo.

Comment: Encontré la definición, si quieres te redacto una respuesta: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @OscarGarcia Puede ser monohilo, y provocar condiciones de carrera; basta con que *interrumpa* un código para responder a un evento, y desde ambos puntos accedan a una misma variable. El punto clave del enlace que indicas es `Ejecutar hasta Completar`. Debido a eso, **no se puede producir** el error que refiero. Monta una respuesta, que te lleves los puntos por las molestias :-)

Comment: Por cierto, por qué no usas `defer` con callback o sin callback y usando el evento `load` para detectar el final de la carga de todo?

Comment: Precisamente en el último enlace explica que eso no es posible (yo lo enlacé precisamente a la Wikipedia como `run-to-completion`. Un evento siempre se pone a la cola de eventos, nunca interrumpe la ejecución actual como podría pasar en Java, C, etc. Gracias, la redactaré más tarde, es hora de comer :)_

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas ;-). Llevo poco con Javascript, así que estoy simplemente *haciendo burradas* a ver que pasa XD

Comment: Te incluiré unos ejemplos de implementaciones alternativas usando callbacks y sin ellos que simplifican tu código y lo harán menos sensible a fallos de carga.

Comment: En mi opinión lo que estás mostrando en tu pregunta tiene que funcionar  y es perfectamente válido en Javascript. Si bien Javascript es monohilo, al ser administrado por eventos, para tu caso, alcanza perfectamente. Nunca se interrumpe la ejecución de ninguna función, simplemente cuando la función termina el manejador de eventos elije otra que esté en condiciones de ejecutarse porque se cumplió el evento sobre el cuál están colgadas. Porque cada vez que ocurre un evento se "encola" la función para ser ejecutada.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario; es lo mismo que me indicó @OscarGarcia en los suyos, con un enlace muy *iluminador*. Sigo esperando alguna respuesta esclarecedora sobre el asunto, que sirva a otros usuarios y se lleve los 25 *puntillos* ;-)

Comment: Quizá me he pasado con las pruebas de concepto ya que estoy mezclando tiempos de carga de la página en el navegador con la gestión de eventos... pero orienté la respuesta a que estás intentando acelerar la carga de tu página retrasando la carga mediante javascript... quizá me equivoqué en la orientación.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript se ejecuta en un único hilo en cada pestaña del navegador. Todos los navegadores lo implementan de la misma manera, aunque algunos ejecutan todos los javascript en el mismo hilo y otros dedican un hilo por cada pestaña.

La ejecución del código nunca es interrumpida por la llegada de un nuevo evento. En su lugar todos los eventos (que tienen un "listener" o "callback") se añaden a una cola de eventos pendientes de ser atendidos.

Los eventos javascript son atendidos en un [bucle de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) similar a éste:

```
while (colaDeEventos.esperarEvento()) {
  colaDeEventos.procesarEvento();
}
```

Si un evento tarda demasiado tiempo en procesarse porque está mal diseñado (por ejemplo hacer una consulta síncrona XHR, caer en un bucle infinito o procesar cantidades elevadas de información) el navegador puede mostrar un mensaje de advertencia al usuario para permitirle detener la ejecución del script y recuperar (relativamente) la estabilidad del navegador o pestaña de navegación.

Tu código nunca sufrirá una condición de carrera gracias a que cada evento se ejecutará en ese bucle en modo ["run-to-complete"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_to_completion_scheduling).

Quizá haya modos más sencillos de acelerar la carga de una página que retrasar la carga de todo, incluida la hoja de estilos.

**Prueba de concepto**

Antes de nada, para usar el servicio de retraso de carga https://www.deelay.me/ sobre HTTPS hay que aceptar la excepción de seguridad :(

Partiremos de este ejemplo para mejorarlo:

```html
<script>
console.log("Inicio");
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.deelay.me/1000/https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://www.deelay.me/2000/https://cdn.rawgit.com/ojgarciab/af3bb1dd3720fa1ab027459bf08df104/raw/8660b7c868ee40237e2578da71c857aba34733c1/ejemplo1.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="https://www.deelay.me" target="_blank">Agregar excepción de seguridad HTTPS</a>
<img src="https://www.deelay.me/3000/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Button_exclamation.png" alt="" width="23" height="22" /></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("Página cargada");
});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("DOM cargado");
});
console.log("Final del DOM");
</script>
```

El resultado puede ser algo como:

```
1.- Inicio           +0
2.- Script ejecutado +3
3.- Final del DOM    +3
4.- DOM cargado      +3
5.- Página cargada   +4
```

El "Script ejecutado" se retrasa debido a la carga previa de la hoja de estilos (1s) del propio javascript que muestra el mensaje (2s).

El script del final del documento ("Final del DOM") y "DOM cargado" se suceden de manera sucesiva y sólo "Página cargada" se retrasa un segundo adicional debido a los tres segundos adicionales desde la carga desde la hoja de estilos (podrían haber sido más si el navegador hubiera parado la interpretación del DOM durante la carga del javascript).

**Agregando `defer` al `<script>`**

```html
<script>
console.log("Inicio");
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.deelay.me/1000/https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://www.deelay.me/2000/https://cdn.rawgit.com/ojgarciab/af3bb1dd3720fa1ab027459bf08df104/raw/8660b7c868ee40237e2578da71c857aba34733c1/ejemplo1.js" defer></script>
<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="https://www.deelay.me" target="_blank">Agregar excepción de seguridad HTTPS</a>
<img src="https://www.deelay.me/3000/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Button_exclamation.png" alt="" width="23" height="22" /></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("Página cargada");
});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("DOM cargado");
});
console.log("Final del DOM");
</script>
```

```
1.- Inicio           +0
2.- Final del DOM    +1
3.- Script ejecutado +2
4.- DOM cargado      +2
5.- Página cargada   +3
```

Ahora se ejecuta el script del final del documento ("Final del DOM") tras la carga de la hoja de estilos (1s) sin esperar la descarga del javascript con el atributo `defer`.

Se ejecuta el script externo tras los dos segundos de retraso e inmediatamente se da por finalizada la carga del "DOM".

Aún tardará un segundo más en finalizar la carga de la página aunque la imagen se puso en cola de descarga desde el primer momento.

Hemos ganado dos segundos hasta "Final del DOM" y un segundo en el resto.

**Agregando la hoja de estilos al final**

```html
<script>
console.log("Inicio");
</script>
<script src="https://www.deelay.me/2000/https://cdn.rawgit.com/ojgarciab/af3bb1dd3720fa1ab027459bf08df104/raw/8660b7c868ee40237e2578da71c857aba34733c1/ejemplo1.js" defer></script>
<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="https://www.deelay.me" target="_blank">Agregar excepción de seguridad HTTPS</a>
<img src="https://www.deelay.me/3000/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Button_exclamation.png" alt="" width="23" height="22" /></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("Página cargada");
});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("DOM cargado");
});
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = 'https://www.deelay.me/1000/https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(link);
console.log("Final del DOM");
</script>
```

```
1.- Inicio           +0
2.- Final del DOM    +0
3.- Script ejecutado +2
4.- DOM cargado      +2
5.- Página cargada   +3
```

Todo el documento completo se analiza y ejecuta de manera casi inmediata (pero usando los estilos por defecto) ahorrando tres segundos desde la prueba de concepto y un segundo respecto a retrasar la carga y ejecución del javascript a costa de ver las hojas de estilo incorrecta durante unos instantes.

La ejecución del script será tras su carga (2s) y se da por finalizado el DOM (aunque aún quede una imagen y una hoja de estilos por cargar, aunque habrá terminado antes que la imagen).

En cuanto esos dos se terminan de cargar (3s desde el comienzo para la imagen y 1s desde "Final del DOM" para la hoja de estilo) se genera la "Página cargada".

**Conclusión**

¿Merece la pena hacer un XHR para obtener la hoja de estilos y javascript que hay que cargar?

- Para acelerar la visualización de la página basta con usar `defer`.
- La mejora en latencia comparado con el tiempo de visualización sin estilos y posterior "transformación mágica" no merece la pena.

Para acelerar la carga de las hojas de estilo lo mejor es hacer uso de la caché del navegador o incluir directamente las hojas de estilo en cada página en el lado del servidor.

En tu código bastaría con esperar a que el DOM estuviera cargado (`document/DOMContentLoaded`) para llamar a tu función `App.Run()`, pero si necesitas hoja de estilos esperaría a la carga de la página (`window/load`).