# Evitar que una función se ejecute exactamente en el mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Para generar un nombre de archivo aleatorio tengo la siguiente microfunción:

```
function generateRandomFileName(){
    return `tmp_${Date.now()}`;
}
```

Esta función corre en nodejs, y se ejecuta de acuerdo a otras funciones como es normal... la cosa es que en este servidor de nodejs, se envia por sockets unos pocos bytes de información, para luego ser escritos de acuerdo a un nombre aleatorio, de esto se encarga la función `generateRandomFileName`, **hay que tener en cuenta que una vez se le hace una muestra a los archivos (se recoge cierta información importante de ellos), estos son eliminados.**

De acuerdo a esto me puse a pensar... Y que pasa si dada la exhuberante casualidad, dos personas hacen esta petición al mismo tiempo y llega esta petición al servidor socket exactamente al mismo tiempo y como resultado los nombres del archivo a escribir son exactamente los mismos?, el resultado sería que la función que se encarga de recoger la información una vez escritos fallaría o se confundiria... ya que hay dos personas escribiendo un archivo super ligero al mismo tiempo...

De que manera puedo evitar esta posible pero destructiva casualidad?

No hay manera de probar esto facilmente, debido a que es demasiado dificil sincronizar todo para que se de la casualidad, por lo que creo que tocaría hacerlo un poco a mente, alguna idea de lo que puedo hacer para evitar esto?, no he intentado nada porque no se que debería hacer.

He pensado tambien lo siguiente:

Si compruebo que no exista primero el archivo, como puede haber una demora en la creación del archivo, el segundo, o incluso tercer usuario al usar la función existsSync de fileSystem puede que les retorne `false` es decir, según ellos el archivo aún no existe, por lo cuál lo crean, esto haría un override automatico al archivo de los otros usuarios, el resultado es que a ninguno de ellos al final le funcionara la extracción de datos, algo como lo siguiente:

```
const fs = require("fs");

/*
   Puede haber un retraso creando el archivo, por lo que puede ser sobreescrito 
   sin querer aunque 'se compruebe que no exista'.
*/
if(fs.existsSync(outputFile)){

}
```

Alguna idea de lo que puedo hacer que definitivamente erradique este problema?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Duda teórica sobre condiciones de carrera en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73816/duda-te%c3%b3rica-sobre-condiciones-de-carrera-en-javascript)

Comment: puedes mirar si hay alguna funcion para crear tu archivo con microtime (incluyendo microsegundos). Con eso es casi imposible de que ocurra un mismo nombre de archivo. tambien puedes generar aleatorios basandoete en el microtime y luego añadir el microtime correspondiente.

Comment: Excelente articulo trauma, me dio a entender muchas cosas sobre JS gracias por postearlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigando un poco, hay dos opciones, la primera era usar:

```
Date.now();
```

La cuál devuelve los milisegundos transcurridos desde cierta fecha, y la segunda es usar los nanosegundos que provee `process.hrtime`:

```
process.hrtime()[1];
```

La segunda opción es bastante precisa, pero aún queda una casi nula probabilidad, que pase algo inesperado, así que recorde lo siguiente, `socket.io`, su instancía en el servidor tiene una propiedad `id` que es única por cada instancia de `socket` entonces se puede conseguir evitar al 100% condiciones de carrera mezclando estos dos conceptos, así fue como llegue a la siguiente conclusión de lo que podía hacer para resolver este problema:

```
function generateRandomFileName(socket){
    return `tmp_${socket.id}_${process.hrtime()[1]}`;
}
```

Con esto el nombre del archivo siempre será distinto.

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar esto se pueden seguir uno o mas métodos, primero de ellos es modificar el nombre que generas para dicho archivo para que no sea un time stamp sino un UUID, para ello puedes usar el siguiente codigo

```
function generateGuid() {
  var result, i, j;
  result = '';
  for(j=0; j<32; j++) {
      if( j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20) 
      result = result + '-';
      i = Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
      result = result + i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Dado que genera el nombre con datos aleatorios sumando que mientras más digitos sean la probabilidad de repeticion tiende a ser nula (nunca cero) es una buena opción si tus datos no son críticos.

Para datos críticos lo que puedes generar es un Singleton que genere los nombres y en base al tiempo y un uuid aleatorio, dependeiendo del tiempo puedes comprobar si dihco bombre de archivo ya existe, el formato seria temp__ y guardarias dicho nombre en un objeto temporal.

Comment: Tu solución es muy buena, me gusta, sin embargo aún existe una probabilidad practicamente nula de que aún hayan overrides.