# ¿Cómo generar nombres/id/paths automaticamente con Firestore en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy usando Firestore para almacenar imágenes, pero dichas imágenes son guardadas con una ruta que depende del nombre del archivo. Pensé que si ya existía la ruta y guardaba una nueva imagen, entonces, se sobrescribe la imagen... ¿Se puede configurar Firestore para que se generen rutas automaticamente?

No me importa como sea el formato de la ruta porque la almaceno en un campo de mi base de datos y luego la consulto para descargar el archivo.

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
export const uploadImagesFirebase = (images) => {
  console.log(firebase.storage());
  const rootImageRef = storageRef.child('answerImages');
    return Promise.all(
    images.map((img) => rootImageRef.child(img.image.name).put(img.image))
  );
};
```

Como ven, el path depende del nombre de la imagen `(img.image.name)`

Comment: En tu base de datos, no se si uses la base de datos de firebase u otra, debes tener un registro de usuarios, hay dos opciones, o que uses el nombre de usuario y a eso le concatenes la ruta de la imagen actual para guardarla en firebase o en la base de datos que tengas, o que uses el ID y hagas lo mismo, en ambos casos no debería haber inconvenientes, puesto que tanto el ID como el nombre de usuario nunca deberían repetirse en una buena BD. Pero no, no puedo darte una respuesta, ya que no tengo conocimientos de firebase, esta entonces es mi opinion de lo que puedes hacer.

Comment: De hecho justo debo aprender firebase dentro de nada por un proyecto, esto me puede ser útil.

Comment: Lo que decidí hacer fue lo que deje como respuesta a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Decidí usar la dependencia [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) con timestamp para generar un id único para cada elemento.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el timestamp en windows no es tan preciso, puede chocar con diferentes usuarios que esten subiendo algo al mismo tiempo, mira lo siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346099/evitar-que-una-funci%c3%b3n-se-ejecute-exactamente-en-el-mismo-tiempo

Comment: Creo que no debería generar conflicto porque uuid no solo hace el id con la hora (que va a ser la del servidor), si no que siempre agrega un factor aleatorio, entonces se hace muy improbable que tengan el mismo nombre. Pero consideraré usar el resto de opciones que me presta uuid para evitarlo en lo posible. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Ah, revisé el enlace, es que fíjate, hablan de que no debe ser un timestamp si no un UUID, y es exactamente lo que tengo, solo que el UUID está basado en el timestamp + un factor aleatorio.